# Issue in creating another collection from result of a mongodb query in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I was trying to create another collection with the result of a query in mongodb using nodejs

The code is working fine if I have only a few number of records. But not working if there is large records.

**Error**

```
[Error: Document exceeds maximum allowed bson size of 16777216 bytes]
```

**Code**

```
MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, function (err, database) {
    if (err) throw err;
    coll = database.collection("smmc_queue");
    coll.insert({
        "startTime": moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY, h:mm:ss a"),
        "caseName": req.body.caseName,
        "author": req.session.user,
        "jobType": 'Query',
        "status": 'In progress',
        "searchDescription": searchDescription,
        "query": searchCondition,
        "sort": sortCondition
    }, function (err, sucessDoc) {
        res.redirect(302, '/queryStatus');
        MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, function (err, database) {
            if (err) throw err;
            collection = database.collection(req.body.caseName);
            collection.find(searchObj, sortObj).toArray(function (err, doc) {
                var ncn = 'query_' + sucessDoc[0]._id.toString();
                if (!err) {
                    coll.update({
                        "_id": sucessDoc[0]._id
                    }, {
                        $set: {
                            "endTime": moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY, h:mm:ss a"),
                            status: "Completed",
                        }
                    }, {
                        upsert: true,
                        multi: true
                    }, function (err, result) {});
                    resultCollection = database.collection(ncn);
                    console.log(typeof doc)
                    console.log(doc.length)
                    resultCollection.insert(doc, function (err, res) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                } else {
                    coll.update({
                        "_id": sucessDoc[0]._id
                    }, {
                        $set: {
                            "endTime": moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY, h:mm:ss a"),
                            status: "Completed",
                            "result": err
                        }
                    }, {
                        upsert: true,
                        multi: true
                    }, function (err, result) {});
                }
            });
        });
    });
})
```

**Console Samples**

```
Search Query : { CARDNO: 821 }
typeof doc : object
doc.length : 756
err (insert to resultCollection) : null

Search Query : { IODATE: { '$gt': Mon Apr 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST) } }
typeof doc : object
doc.length : 374010
err (insert to resultCollection) : [Error: Document exceeds maximum allowed bson size of 16777216 bytes]
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this fails is because when you are **inserting** your doc value is an array, of the "lengths" that you are reporting.

While an **array** of documents is fine to issue to insert, it is not the "individual" document size that is in question, but the **whole** insert. So you are breaking the maximum BSON size, because the "request" to insert is larger than the maximum (16MB).

What you **need** to do is break this up, try amounts of `500` at a time.

```
var last = 0;
for ( var i=0; i < doc.length; i+= 500 ) {
    resultCollection.insert( doc.slice(last, i) );
    last = i;
}
resultCollection.insert( doc.slice(last, doc.length) );
```

Or something possibly better than that.

But generally, break up the array. You can only do the limit (16MB) **per request**.

Comment: Will it works if I use async each or something? Or is there another way to split it up?

Comment: @SreekeshOkky you still need to iterate the results somehow. Though and array is valid, what you are sending is to big. I have included some basic code as a sample.

Comment: I have used async eachSeries. Its working fine. Thank u so much for guiding me on the right path

Comment: @SreekeshOkky As I said, something better. But as long as it is broken up. Possibly look at iterating a cursor rather then using `.toArray()` to save on memory.